# Delphi - Array of Ansichar to String and Vice versa

Tags: string, delphi, templates, fingerprint

I have been given an SDK which takes a fingerprint template from a device, i need to store this in a SQL database and then reload to the FP device.

The SDK FP template data is defined as `template_data:array[0..1568] of ansichar;`.

The template is stored in database ok by converting the template data to a string using code below:

```
SetString(s, user.template_data[i].template_data, 
          user.template_data[i].template_length);
```

The problem comes when converting the string back from the database to the template data, it only copies the first 3 characters when using `StrLCopy`

```
StrLCopy(PChar(@user.template_data[0].template_data),
         PChar(s), FieldByName('FPLen').AsInteger);
```

When debugging the code i notice that there 4 character in the template is a null character so i guess that's why only the first 3 are copied.

Need a solution to copy the string with the null characters to an array of ansichar.

Comment: Use `Move` to copy the data

Comment: Hi David,Tried Move but it doesn't appear to work as the first three character should be FMR but when i Move the data is not the same  Move(s,user.template_data[0].template_data,FieldByName('FPLen').AsInteger);

Comment: Move works fine, mistake must be in your code.

Comment: Better operate over byte string ([AsBytes](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TParam.AsBytes) for writing, [AsBytes](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TField.AsBytes) for reading). It was certainly not meant to be a displayable string (just because there are #0 chars inside the string). What is the original declaration (in a C like language, as I believe it comes with it)? What is the DBMS that you use? Which client database library do you use? In short, I think you are using wrong data type.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Move alongside with FillChar as David pointed out

```
FillChar(ArrayVariable[0], length(ArrayVariable) * sizeof(char), #0);
Move(StringVariable[1], ArrayVariable[0], length(s) * sizeof(char));
```

And if the null characters still messes something up, you can try "normalizing" the content of the variable with a simple loop (as you cannot use StringReplace because every null characters is cast into a #0 PChar)

```
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  i:=1;
  while i <= Length(StringVariable) do begin
    if StringVariable[i] = #0 then begin
      Delete(StringVariable, i, 1)
    end else begin
      i := i+1;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't just this?

```
function ArrayToString(const a: array of AnsiChar): string;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  for I := Low(a) to High(a) do
    Result := Result + a[i]
end;
```